# RDP accidently disabled in a VM in Azure

Tags: azure

I am not able to access my VM in azure because I accidently disabled RDP services in a VM in Azure through gepedit.msc.My VM is working and I can access my hosted URL through browser. Please advice me how can I get into my system.I tried with windows powershell but was unsuccessfull.

This is how I disabled RDP services in the VM in Azure.

Run--> gpedit.msc --> computer configuration --> Administrative templates --> Windows components --> Remote Desktop services --> Remote Desktop Session Host --> Connections --> Allow users to connect remotely by using remote Desktop Services --> Disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the VM Agent and use that to reset the rdp configuration.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/03/06/enable-rdp-or-reset-password-with-the-vm-agent/

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to reach it through remote PowerShell, as described in this article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Let's hope that helps!